# Year, P, and grade

Tags: reading

I'm a bit confused on the England system when I try to understand the English levels on reading, writing etc.

Oxford (https://cdn.oxfordowl.co.uk/2017/02/20/14/11/00/314/px_orcs.pdf), is using **Year** and **P**, for example, Year 2/P3 is around Oxford Reading Tree level 7 - 11.

Does P3 means the 3rd grade of Primary school? What does Year mean then?

Scholastic is using **Grade**, for example, Harry Potter, according to https://www.scholastic.com/teachers/bookwizard/#cart/cleanup , is for Grade 4-6. Is this Grade 4-6 same as P4-P6? or Year 4-6?

Comment: This isn't a matter of the English *language* so much as it is about the classification used in a particular educational system. The use of *P* or *year* would be the same if translated to any other language, and by the same token are not applicable in other methods or standards for scoring reading ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grades marked with P are Scottish, the ones marked as Year *X* are English, while "grade" refers to the US system.

This chart from [this PDF](http://www.educationista.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/UK-US-Ireland-Australia-school-years-and-grades.pdf) should help you understand, in general, how it compares:

[image]

Side note: As an American I can tell you that "Pre K" is also called "preschool" and "junior high" is called "middle school", at least where I live.

Comment: I'll point out that this answer is incomplete, because every country is different, and sometimes different states within that country are different. That chart lists England, Scotland, Ireland, and the USA, but there's also a number of other English-speaking countries that have their own schemas.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how is the "Age" computed?

Comment: @athos That's the age of the children in years. This means for example that 11 year olds in the US will be in 5th or 6th grade.

Comment: @Laurel sorry i didn't put myself clearly. Let's say US schools started from Jan 2nd each year, then for a boy born on 2000-06-30, at 2011 Jan, is he considered at age 11 or 10?